# Удаление столбца из csv файла по номеру

Tags: python, csv

Есть CSV файл, в нем 378 столбцов и 49000 строк. Названия столбцов:

```
'id' 'riln' 'gold' ...
```

Запятые в качестве разделителей не используются.

Как удалить один столбец в данном файле?

Comment: Основная задача - это удалить столбец из `csv` - файла? Почему вы хотите делать это при помощи `pandas`?

Comment: я только начал разбирать в работе с данными, если можно то подскажите способ?

Comment: Можно сделать с помощью консольной утилиты `cut`. Например, если столбцы разделены запятой, команда `cut -d',' -f-99,101- file.csv` удалит сотый столбец. Отредактируйте вопрос в соответствии с реальной задачей.

Comment: Так как столбцов много, вам еще лучше уточнить, известен номер столбца или его название?

Comment: 'gold' 5 столбец

Comment: @mkkik, почему вы удалили метку `[python]` ?

Comment: @den1000, что у вас используется в качестве разделителей? Пробелы, табуляции, что-то еще?

Comment: пробелы стоят   (gold id riln)

Comment: @MaxU, потому что ТС устраивал любой способ, как я понял. Без привязки к ЯП.

Comment: @mkkik, по-моему, из комментариев и тем более из вопроса это не следует...

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться Python + Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# порядковые номера столбцов, которые нужно удалить (нумерация столбцов начинается с 0)
cols2drop = [4]

# список столбцов, которые нужно прочитать    
cols = [i for i in range(378) if i not in cols2drop]

# чтение нужных столбцов и запись в CSV
(pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv', usecols=cols, delim_whitespace=True)
   .to_csv(r'/path/to/result.csv', index=False, sep=' '))
```